# Cycle notation and transpositions

Tags: permutations, notation, permutation-cycles

For example, consider the permutation
$$ \pi=\left(\begin{matrix}
1&2&3&4&5\\
4&3&2&5&1
\end{matrix}\right).$$
You can write it with two cycles as
$$  \pi =(145)(23).$$

Now I want to write $\pi$ as a product of transpositions. I know one way to do that is
$$ \pi =(14)(45)(23)$$
because $(145)=(14)(45) $. However, I don't understand the logic behind this notation. Transpositions are cycles as well, so wouldn't that notation imply $\pi(1)=4 $, and $\pi(4)=1\ne 5$ (according to the first transposition)? Or $\pi(4)=5 $ and $\pi(5)=4\ne 1$ (according to the second transposition)? So could someone elaborate this notation to me? I guess that I have misunderstood the cycle notation.

Comment: The key is that the cycles of $(145)(23)$ are disjoint, that is, the numbers in one cycle are completely different from the numbers in the other cycle. This is the simplified form where you can compute $\pi (4)$ if you wanted. In the case you have below, the 2-cycles are not disjoint, so you wouldn't want to compute $\pi (4)$ directly from this expression. The reason being that it's confusing like you've observed. That's not to say that writing a permutation as a product of 2-cycles is useless, and you will see when you learn about the alternating groups.

Comment: Each transposition is a function, and written in order they represent a composition of functions, so $(14)(45)$ acting on $4$ has $(45)$ send $4$ to $5$, but then $(14)$ doesn't change $5$, so the output of the composite function is $5$. On the other hand, $(14)(45)$ acting on $5$ has $(45)$ send $5$ to $4$, but then $(14)$ sends it to $1$,  so the output of the composite function is $1$.

Comment: See also this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/195021/693577

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication of cycles can be written as *composition* of permutations (order right to left). This way we can see the commonality when representing $\pi$ as multiplication of transpositions as well as multiplication of other cycles.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\pi}&\color{blue}{=(1\,4\,5)(2\,3)}\\
> &=(1\,4\,5)(2)(3)\circ(1)(2\,3)(4)(5)\\
> &=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1&2&3&4&5\\
> 4&3&2&5&1\\
> \end{pmatrix}
> \\
> \\
> \color{blue}{\pi}&\color{blue}{=(1\,4)(4\,5)(2\,3)}\\
> &=(1\,4)(2)(3)(5)\circ\left((1)(2)(3)(4\,5)\circ(1)(2\,3)(4)(5)\right)\\
> &=(1\,4)(2)(3)(5)\circ(1)(2\,3)(4\,5)\\
> &=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1&2&3&4&5\\
> 4&3&2&5&1\\
> \end{pmatrix}
> \\
> \\
> \color{blue}{\pi}&\color{blue}{=(1\,4)(4\,5)(2\,3)}\\
> &=\left((1\,4)(2)(3)(5)\circ(1)(2)(3)(4\,5)\right)\circ(1)(2\,3)(4)(5)\\
> &=(1\,4\,5)(2)(3)\circ(1)(2\,3)(4\,5)\\
> &=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1&2&3&4&5\\
> 4&3&2&5&1\\
> \end{pmatrix}
> \end{align*}